# Not able to update my feature branch after deleting a particular commit from master

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I have deleted a particular commit from master(not top commit) branch and I have already created a feature branch. For example, I have created a feature branch X from master and now I deleted a particular commit from master branch. After developing feature, I am always merging master branch in feature branch through following process.

Go to code path in git bash and run the following command

```
git checkout master
git fetch origin
git checkout X
git merge master
git push origin X
```

and I am able to merge master branch earlier but not able to get after deleting that commit from master. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to find the issue. The branches are **not in sync now**. The thing is that I have first created feature branch and then delete particular commit from master branch. So there are two ways to fix this. First create new branch put all changes there or delete that particular commit from feature branch which was deleted from master.